# How can I post data to drupal 8 custom field via rest api?

Tags: drupal-8

I can post title, body to drupal via rest api.
But not the custom fields like images, text and so on.
How can I post data to **drupal 8** custom field via rest api?

```
{
    "_links":{
        "type": {
            "href":"http://d8.168seo.cn/rest/type/node/movie"
        }},
    "type": [
        {

            "target_id":"movie"
        }

    ],
    "title":[
        {
            "value":"来自seo"
        }
    ],
    "body":[

    {
        "value":"这是一个pstmannei"
    }

    ]   
}
```

Comment: youre going to have to give us more than that.  What have you tried? do you have any code (thats useful) that we can look at?  At the moment your question is so vague its impossible to answer.

Comment: I think it's similar format with `body`, just change the body with custom field name. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/3-post-for-creating-content-entities